# VBA delete columns based on selected cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to delete 4 columns before Active cell but i don't know which cell the user will select. I mean if the Active cell is "H3" then i will delete (D,E,F,G) entire columns. 
any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
range(activecell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-1),activecell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-4)).Columns.Delete
```

Try this out on a sample sheet before putting it to use.